# Help with doctype issues

Tags: html, css, doctype, quirks-mode

I am having issues making my footer stick to the bottom of the page in all browsers.

I have the following document structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <ul>
                    <li>home</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="expander"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer" class="expander">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS is:

```
body
{
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -116px; 
}

.expander
{
 height: 116px;
}

#footer
{
 width: 100%;
}

#header ul
{
 list-style: none outside none;
 clear: both;
 margin: 0;
}

#header li
{
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 85px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

When used without any doc type, the page renders as I intend it to in Chrome and Firefox. In IE8, however, the list item tabs are on separate lines

When I add an XHTML doctype, the page renders correctly in IE8 except the footer is not drawn at the bottom of the page in IE8, Chrome or Firefox, i.e. the footer sits directly below the menu bar.

Example doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you should supply more details.

Comment: Use sticky footer to have your footer at the bottom of the page. http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: First immediate observation that won't fix the problem. You're doctype is incorrect. It's for sites that are served as XML only but I doubt you are doing that. Change it to the XHTML1 version.

Comment: I think you just discovered quirks mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with the `DOCTYPE` in the code:

Changing:

```
body
{
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

to:

```
html, body
{
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the footer stay at the bottom of the page
i.e.

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Note: this solution is thought to avoid wrapper height tricks/problems

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the wrong doctype, as I mentioned above, changing or removing doctypes is never an option. Essentially, it's the set of rules you are telling the browser you are using to create the page. You can't be changing the rules in midstream or on a whim. Change/remove the doctype, change the rules.

Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things work. Inept at best, it's a decade or more behind all others in modern standards and compliance. If it's working in FF and Chrome then your markup is most likely correct.

Life has just called and I hope to give more info later.

Comment: Absolutely right about the doctype! Just an addition regarding the browser: most of the "normal" people, sadly, use IE (6 Too!!!!!). So we, as web developers, must test things a lot on IE too

Comment: @steweb - I didn't say don't test in IE. I said you can't trust it to do anything correctly and you can't use it for a reference for how things work.

Comment: I never used IE as a reference? It's a turd of a browser. Cheers for the feedback. I did, however, test in it which was when I noticed the issue.